# insert None based on indexes

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dataframe, if-statement, while-loop

am trying to fit in None's if there is any index missing in the list.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9]
```

In the above list, i wanna *fit in none's at 6,7 and 10*

```
end result = [1,2,3,4,5,None,None,8,9,None]
```

I wont be having any missing value until element 5. But after that, i may miss all elements or few.
Am trying to make my list length 10 by inserting None's in the missed elements.
few sample missing elements :

```
1 - [1,2,3,4,5,6] , expected result - [1,2,3,4,5,6, None, None, None, None] 
2 - [a,b,c,d,e,h,i ], expected result - [a,b,c,d,e,None,None,h,i]
```

*Note: The difference between any of the index is 1. Until index 5( e) ill be getting all the values, so am using the below logic*

Logic - I have used the distance -

```
    distance = (-1 * (mylist[3]-mylist[4]))
    distance = 1
    index_missing_distance = (-1*(mylist[3] -mylist[5])) which is equal to 2 (i.e for the above sample 1 ) 
distance between mylist[3] - mylist[6] will be 3... so based on the index_missing_distance ill fill my None values in that index.
```

Code:

```
if len(mylist) < 7:
     if index_missing_distance == 2:
          mylist[7:1] = [None,None, None, None]
elif len(mylist) < 8:
     do something
elif len(mylist) < 9:
.....
```

Suppose if its 3 then do another if else. Like this I will have to fit None's based on how many values are missing. I had to write so many if cases which is making my code complicated. Need some help on this. Can we use something like while loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added new example for you please test it.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9]

print([i if i in mylist else None for i in range(min(mylist), 11])
```

Alphabetical:

```
import string

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g']
index_start = string.ascii_lowercase.index('a')
index_end = string.ascii_lowercase.index('g')

print([i if i in mylist else None for i in string.ascii_lowercase[index_start:index_end + 1]])
```

Comment: can you check my sample - 2 ? I am using a distance method to calculate, but my list elements might be of alphabets as well.

Comment: `distance = (-1 * (mylist[3]-mylist[4]))
index_missing = (-1*(mylist[3] -mylist[5])) which is equal to 2 (i.e for the above sample 1 )`
this is the formula, taht am using for the character also(Bounding box values) That means my text is in the form of list.

Comment: I added for you new example

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index by searching, then insert None into the array.

```py
import numpy as np
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9]

for i in range(6,11):
    if not i in mylist:
        index = np.searchsorted(mylist, i)
        mylist = mylist[0:index] + [None] + mylist[index:]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function that returns first five list items unchanged and puts the next five items to positions given by the `n5` argument while substituing `None` for missing items.

Basically the `n5` argument is how the last 5 items would look like for a complete sequence.

```
def none10(lst, n5):
    s5 = set(lst[5:])
    return lst[0:5] + [x if x in s5 else None for x in n5]

print(none10([11,13,12,4,5,  7,9], [6,7,8,9,10]))
print(none10(['a','b','c','d','e',  'h','i'], ['f','g','h','i','j']))
```

Output is (edited to show the 5+5 split):

```
[11,13,12,4,5,   None,7,None,9,None]
['a','b','c','d','e',   None,None,'h','i',None]
```

Comment: i definitely have to use the logic, can you replace my if else usinga while loop ?

Comment: I don't understand your response _"no ill not be knowing the n5"_.

Comment: am running this on 1000 samples, so i cant identify the n5 which you have already declared. Thats the reason am using the distance as metric to know the index. And my len (list) is not always 10, but its greater than 5.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably don't fully understand your question. Could you add more input -> output examples?